# java.util.Calendar

Tags: java, calendar, java.util.calendar

My application:

```
System.out.print("Please enter date (and time): ");
myTask.setWhen(
   input.nextInt(),
   input.nextInt(),
   input.nextInt(),
   input.nextInt(),
   input.nextInt());
```

My setter:

```
public void setWhen(int year, int month, int date, int hourOfDay, int minute){
    this.year = year;
    this.month = month;
    this.date = date;
    this.hourOfDay = hourOfDay;
    this.minute = minute;
```

It throws an exception when it ready for the user to enter date and time though. Also, what will happen if user enters 4/7/2013 1:30pm as opposed to 4, 7, 2013, 13, 30?
Thanks.

Comment: What Exception is thrown?

Comment: Can you add the code that defines `input` so we can see what you've done?

Comment: `input` is a `Scanner`, I believe. The question is about comparing 1:30pm to 13:30.

Answer (score 0):

Code should be like this (just quick idea):

```
System.out.print("Please enter date (and time): ");
String inputText;
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
inputText = scanner.nextLine();
scanner.close();
//parse input and parsed put as input parameter for your setwhen() method
setWhen(myOwnParserForInputFromConsole(inputText));
```

Comment: You need a promotion... How this may help? The question was how to write `myOwnParserForInputFromConsole`.

Comment: Thanks! What do I put in the spot for "myOwnParserForInputFromConsole"?

Comment: you need check if input is in expected format - here you need integer on line. so implement to check that input is integer.

Answer (score 0):

From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28int%29), `nextInt` throws "`InputMismatchException` - if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range". This means that you cannot blindly call `nextInt` and hope that the input will be an `int`.

You probably should read the input as a `String` and perform checks on that input so see whether it is valid.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    //read year
    final String yearString = scanner.next();
    final int year;
    try {
        year = Integer.parseInt(yearString);
        //example check, pick appropriate bounds
        if(year < 2000 || year > 3000) throw new NumberFormatException("Year not in valid range");
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to parse year.", ex);
    }
    final String monthString = scanner.next();
    final int month;
    try {
        month = Integer.parseInt(monthString);
        //example check, pick appropriate bounds
        if(month < 1 || month > 12) throw new NumberFormatException("Month not in valid range");
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to parse month.", ex);
    }
    //and the rest of the values
}
```

Then, when you have all the inputs and they are known to be valid, then call `setWhen`.

Obviously you can, instead of throwing an exception, try and read the number again.

Answer (score 0):

Another way by using the standards:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class Calend {

   public static void main( String[] args ) throws ParseException {
      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
      DateFormat formatter =
         DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(
            DateFormat.FULL, DateFormat.FULL );
      DateFormat scanner;
      Date date;

      scanner = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(
         DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT );
      date = scanner.parse( "7/4/2013 21:01:05" );
      cal.setTime( date );
      System.out.println( formatter.format( cal.getTime()));

      scanner = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(
         DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.MEDIUM );
      date = scanner.parse( "7 avr. 2013 21:01:05" );
      cal.setTime( date );
      System.out.println( formatter.format( cal.getTime()));

      scanner = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(
         DateFormat.FULL, DateFormat.FULL );
      date = scanner.parse( "dimanche 7 avril 2013 21 h 01 CEST" );
      cal.setTime( date );
      System.out.println( scanner.format( cal.getTime()));
   }
}
```

If you want to use a different Locale, it exists a constructor in DateFormat which handle it.